# What exactly is the git extensions "Amend last commit" button doing?

Tags: git

I've accidentally pressed the "Amend last commit" button in git extensions. My last commit has already been pushed/shared with others, so I actually do not want to do that.

I usually used this button like this:

1. click on the button – it loads the previous message
2. stage new changes
3. when click on the button again, it performs `git commit --amend`

Now, I don't want to click the button again. I'd rather like to overwrite the message and do regular commit.

The thing that confuses me is: When I close the commit dialog and open it again, I can see the old message in the box.

Can someone please confirm if this is how buttons will behave, and I don't "amend" anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone please confirm if this is how buttons will behave, and I don't "amend" anything?

Just tested this on my local system, it will create a new commit and not amend the previous one.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Silly me - could have done it myself on another repo...

Comment: @tishmayeah yeah, but not a problem. Cheers!